# Arduino - Pixycam interferes with Blinky Example

Tags: arduino

I have a pixicam connected to an Arduino Uno. The pixi.init() method seems to be interfering with a normal blinky program. Here is the smallest reproducable program:

```
#include<SPI.h>
#include<Pixy.h>

Pixy pixy;


// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  pixy.init();

}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
}
```

If I comment out the pixi.init() line then the program works as normal (blinking on and off). When the line is not commented out, the light fails to blink.

Comment: Looks like the pixy uses SPI. On the UNO, SPI uses pins 10-13 ([see this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI)). 
The built-in LED uses pin 13. So there is a conflict. Also, [arduino.se] is a better place for this question.

Comment: This is in fact the issue. If you post as an answer I will accept.